# Map Service for ASP.NET

Tags: google-maps

I am planning to do project for visualizing store outlets of a brand in a demographic area. When a user selects an area, it will show (only) the store outlets of the brand. The visual will show major roads, junctions and the store locations of the brand only. I am planning to develop it as a ASP.NET website.

I think, there will be free to use map services. And there will be controls that can be used in asp.net website which will utilize theses service data.

What could be the best map service for this? (Is OpenStreetMap useful for this?)

What could be the UI control for this? Is OpenLayers and CloudMade something like these UI controls for ASP.NET ?

Also can I use multiple map serives? (Service A for India data, Service B for Australia data, etc) ?

I am expecting to do this as a project in my curriculum. So I am looking for products that are free to use.

Please share your ideas.

Thanks

Lijo

Answer (score -1):

Programmable web has a great list of such APIs. http://www.programmableweb.com/

http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Mapping

You can't do much better than Google Maps and your best bet is probably to use their javascript or web services APIs.